# Warning filesize stat failed for my post

Tags: warnings

How to fix...

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /home/mrsa/public_html/wp-content/uploads/classified-listing/2022/12/1_20220221_045212_0000.png in /home/mrsa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/classified-listing/app/Helpers/Functions.php on line 998
```

Thank you.

Comment: This appears to be an error in a plugin called `classified-listing`; you should ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: thanks for ur help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.